# .NET MVC Web App Active directory login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, iis, azure-active-directory

I am making a web application which authenticates the user from Azure active directory. When i run this application on IIS Express it works fine. But when deploy it on my server (local IIS), it authenticates fine. But after authentication it comes back to the IIS Express url. For example if on IIS Express after authentication from Azure Active directory it was coming back to localhost:4435, then on local IIS it is coming to this same url localhost:4435 again.
I am not sure how to make it work.

Comment: Did you add a repy URL in the Azure portal?
1. Sign in to the Azure portal (https://portal.azure.com)
2. On the top bar, click on your account and under the Directory list, choose the Active Directory tenant containing your application (you don't need to do that if you are only part of one AAD)
3. Click on More Services in the left hand nav, and choose Azure Active Directory.
4. Click on App registrations and find your app.
5. In the Settings, click on "Reply URLs", and add the URL of your web site as deployed.
6. in the Web.Config, you might also have to change the reply URL

Comment: Are you making a redirect after the authentication is done maybe?

Comment: Thank you that was it. Adding the reply URL in Azure portal did the job. I didn't know I had to do that. This is my first time doing authentication for Azure active directory.